# How to use replaceWith to replace the content to in dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
myHtml = '
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>'

$(myHtml).find('.inner').replaceWith('<h2>hello</h2>')

console.log(myHtml)
```

I am trying to replace my inner divs with some other content, but `myHtml` doesn't change after running replaceWith. I suspect it is because it's not part of the DOM tree. Am I right? How do I work around this?

Thanks

Comment: From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/): _"The .replaceWith() method, like most jQuery methods, returns the jQuery object so that other methods can be chained onto it. However, it must be noted that the original jQuery object is returned. This object refers to the element that has been removed from the DOM, not the new element that has replaced it."_

Comment: `$(myHtml).find('.inner').replaceWith('<h2>hello</h2>')`  Converts the string into Elements, it then finds the inner class, and replaces them with the h2.  And then..... nothing.  You don't do anything with the Elements.  They're never added to the page or anything.  And changing the Elements is not going to change the original string.

Comment: Ah yes I see that now. So if I want to get a modified string I would have to put $(myHtml) in a variable, then replace, and then call .outerHTML on the $myHtml element to get the new string.

Comment: Heh just saw your answer which did pretty much that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
//fix the new lines in the string
myHtml = '\
  <div class="outer">\
    <div class="inner"></div>\
    <div class="inner"></div>\
    <div class="inner"></div>\
    <div class="inner"></div>\
  </div>';

//store the changed html back in the string
myHtml = $(myHtml)
           .find('.inner')
           .replaceWith('<h2>hello</h2>')
           //end the find() to go back to the orignal Elements
           .end()
           //get the new complete html
           .prop('outerHTML');

console.log(myHtml)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you can use new es6 ` for multiline strings

Comment: I tried to leave it as close to the original as possible.

Comment: My original code is in coffeescript, hence it's written as it is.